# Add a button in a popup html/js

Tags: javascript, html, button, popup, mapbox

Hello everyone I'm looking to add a button on a popup mapbox like this in html / js could you help me please

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [what](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code? At least the html code.  This should add the button in the popup.

This is similar to what I think you are showing in your image.  It's called a tooltip from https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp.  I added the code for the button.  Without your code we don't know exactly what you are looking for.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Top Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Your JavaScript:

```
function myFunction{
    alert("Add your code here");
}
```